# Can't get the user_meta correctly

Tags: user-meta

I have this code below:

```
function get_user_fields($user, $output = true, $main_title = 'Anmäld till kurs/kurser', $course_update = false) {   
    if ($output === true) {
        if (strlen($title)>0) {
            echo '<h3>' . $main_title . '</h3>';
        }
    }

    //Get locations (course-categories taxonomy) that starts with kurser_ in it's permalink (slug)
    $locations = get_categories_with_slug('kurser_');

    //Get list of all categorycourses
    $categorycourses = get_terms('categorycourses');

    $save_meta = array(); //When no output, use function for storing metadata-array to save
    foreach($locations as $location) {
        if ($output === true) {
            echo '<h3 class="location">'.$location->name.'</h3>';            
        } 

        foreach($categorycourses as $categorycourse) {
            //When a coursecategory has location as it's parent, then show courses for category
            if ($categorycourse->parent == $location->cat_ID) {
                wp_reset_query();
                $args = array('post_type' => 'course',
                    'tax_query' => array(
                        array(
                            'taxonomy' => 'categorycourses',
                            'field' => 'slug',
                            'terms' => $categorycourse->slug,
                        ),
                    ),
                 );

                 $loop = new WP_Query($args);
                 if($loop->have_posts()) {
                    $course_field_name = 'course_' . get_the_ID();

                    //Check when updating course                           
                    if ($course_update === true) {
                        echo 'course update is true';
                        //Course is selected by user in db, is it set as reserve?

                        if (get_user_meta($user->ID, $course_field_name) == 1) {
                            echo 'course field name is set';
                            //User is selected as reserve for this course in db
                            if (get_user_meta($user->ID, $course_field_name.'_reserve') == 1) {
                                 echo 'course field reserve is 1';
                                //Can user be selected as non-reserve?
                                //(course is not full any longer)
                                $nr_available = intval(get_field('nr_available'));
                                                            echo 'nr available = ' . $nr_available;

                                if ($nr_available > 0) {
                                       //User is no longer reserve for this course, save info to db
                                        update_usermeta($user->ID, $course_field_name, 0);  //FOR TESTING
                                       update_usermeta($user->ID, $course_field_name.'_reserve', 0);  
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    if ($output === true) {                        
                        echo '<h4 class="rubrik">'.$categorycourse->name.'</h4>';                   
                        echo '<table class="form-table courses" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"><thead>';
                        echo '<tr><th>Kursnamn</th><th>Startvecka</th><th>Veckodag</th><th>Starttid</th><th>Pris</th><th>Antal platser</th>';
                        echo '</tr>';
                        echo '</thead>';
                        echo '<tbody>';
                    }

                    while($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post();
                        $nr_available = intval(get_field('nr_available'));
                        $status_available_full = 0;
                        if ($nr_available == 0) {
                            $nr_message = 'fullt';
                            $status_available_full = 1;
                        }   
                        else if ($nr_available<=4) {
                            $nr_message = 'fåtal platser';
                        }  
                        else {
                            $nr_message = 'platser finns';
                        }

                        if ($output === true) {                                                                                    
                            $checked = get_user_meta($user->ID, 'course_' . get_the_ID(), true); 
                            if ($checked == 1) {
                                $checked = ' checked="checked"';                              
                            }
                            else {
                                $checked = ' ';
                            }
                            echo '<tr>';
                            echo '<td class="title course-name">';
                            echo '<input type="checkbox"' . $checked . 'name="course_' . get_the_ID() . '">&nbsp;' . get_the_title();
                            //If course is full then be able to book pupil as reserve
                            if ($status_available_full === 1) {
                                echo '<span class="reserve">(reserv)</span>';
                             }
                            echo '</td>';                       
                            echo '<td class="title start-week">' . get_field('start_week') . '</td>';                                                        
                            echo '<td class="title week-day">' . get_field('week_day') . '</td>';
                            echo '<td class="title start-time">' . get_field('start_time') . '</td>';  
                            echo '<td class="title price">' . get_field('course_cost') . '</td>';

                            echo '<td class="title available">' . $nr_message . '</td>';
                            echo '</tr>';
                        }
                        else {
                            //Add info to array when using not output
                            $save_meta[] = array(
                                'course' => $course_field_name,
                                'is_reserve' => $status_available_full
                            );   

                        }                        
                    endwhile;
                    if ($output === true) {
                        echo '</tbody>';
                        echo '</table>';
                    }
                 }             
            }

        } //End foreach categorycourses

    } //End foreach locations

    //Return array when no output is done
    if ($output !== true) { 
        return $save_meta;
    }
}

/* SAVE EXTRA FIELDS */

/* helper-function to save extra fields */
function save_user_fields($user_id) {
    if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_user', $user_id ) )
    return false;

    //Save values of checkbox-fields into db
    $save_meta = get_user_fields($current_user, false);  //False tells that no output should be done  

    //Go through all courses and save them
    foreach($save_meta as $current_meta) {
        $course = $current_meta['course'];
        $is_reserve = $current_meta['is_reserve'];
        $update = 0;
        if (isset($_POST[$course])) {
            $chkbox = $_POST[$course];
            if ($chkbox == 'on') {
                $update = 1;
            }
        }
        //Save values from form into db
        update_usermeta($user_id, $course, $update);                    //Save course into db with format course_{id of course)
        update_usermeta($user_id, $course . '_reserve', $is_reserve);  //Save if user is reserve (1) or not (0) for this course
    }
}

//Hooks for user (Update/add)
add_action('personal_options_update', 'save_user_fields');
add_action('edit_user_profile_update', 'save_user_fields');
add_action('user_register', 'save_user_fields'); //When adding new users
```

I use function save_user_fields for saving meta-data for user into database. I'm not sure I can use `$current_user` variable inside this function? (when calling get_user_fields)

Basically, the code is generating a list of custom taxonomy categories in userprofile with checkbox and when updating user-profile the value of the checkboxes (category selected or not) are saved into db. This seems to work.

I'm saving this metadata in `save_user_fields()`

```
//Save course into db with format course_{id of course) (1=checked, 0 = unchecked)
update_usermeta($user_id, $course, $update);           

//Save if user is reserve (1) or not (0) for this course
update_usermeta($user_id, $course . '_reserve', $is_reserve);
```

**I wonder why the code does not get past the statement (in get_user_fields-function, beginning of "the loop"**) `if (get_user_meta($user->ID, $course_field_name) == 1) {` ?

It does not echo out 'course field name is set'

I'm also using the plugin Advanced Custom Fields, so therefore I'm using `get_field()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved this:

The first issue as that the incorrect User-object was sent to the function (Actuall just an empty string)
**Solved it by writing this:**

```
function save_user_fields($user_id) {
    if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_user', $user_id ) )
    return false;

    //Save values of checkbox-fields into db
    $current_user = new WP_User($user_id);
    $save_meta = get_user_fields($current_user, false);  //False tells that no output should be done  

    //Go through all courses and save them
    foreach($save_meta as $current_meta) {
        $course = $current_meta['course'];
        $is_reserve = $current_meta['is_reserve'];
        $update = 0;
        if (isset($_POST[$course])) {
            $chkbox = $_POST[$course];
            if ($chkbox == 'on') {
                $update = 1;
            }
        }
        //Save values from form into db
        update_usermeta($user_id, $course, $update);                    //Save course into db with format course_{id of course)
        update_usermeta($user_id, $course . '_reserve', $is_reserve);  //Save if user is reserve (1) or not (0) for this course
    }
}
```

**Next issue:**
With help from Karine's (**THANKS!**) answer I used true in get_user_meta() because I wanted the actual value of the field in meta_user_table, not an array.

```
if ($course_update === true) {

    //Course is selected by user in db, is it set as reserve?
    if (intval(get_user_meta($user->ID, $course_field_name, true)) == 1) {
        //User is selected as reserve for this course in db
        if (get_user_meta($user->ID, $course_field_name.'_reserve', true) == 1) {
            //Can user be selected as non-reserve?
            //(course is not full any longer)
            $nr_available = intval(get_field('nr_available'));

            if ($nr_available > 0) {
                   //User is no longer reserve for this course, save info to db
                   update_usermeta($user->ID, $course_field_name.'_reserve', 0);  
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**And now the issue that made me completly mad**, even if I should have seen this earlier on...
The code-snippet above was for setting/getting information about courses (and saving the metadata-array), but it was **NOT** inside of the loop. It was at

```
if($loop->have_posts()) {
$course_field_name = 'course_' . get_the_ID();
```

The same issue for the actual comparision of reserves and nr_available, so I simply moved that block inside of the loop like this (and made minor changes):

```
 while($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post();
    $course_field_name = 'course_' . get_the_ID();

     //Check when updating course                           
    if ($course_update === true && $course_id == get_the_ID()) {

        //Course is selected by user in db, is it set as reserve?
        if (intval(get_user_meta($user->ID, $course_field_name, true)) == 1) {
            //User is selected as reserve for this course in db
            if (get_user_meta($user->ID, $course_field_name.'_reserve', true) == 1) {
                //Can user be selected as non-reserve?
                //(course is not full any longer)
                $nr_available = intval(get_field('nr_available'));

                if ($nr_available > 0) {
                       //User is no longer reserve for this course, save info to db
                       update_usermeta($user->ID, $course_field_name.'_reserve', 0);  
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try `get_user_meta($user->ID, $course_field_name, true)` ?
By default, `get_user_meta()` returns an array

See http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_user_meta